# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value, UITableViewCell, cellForRowAtIndexPath - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8, xcode7

I am debugging this error since 6 hours now ...

I want to save the text of a cells UITextField in my contact.nametitle Object. 
And the following error occurs.

```
func copyEntriesGeneralInfo()
{

    for iP in self.iPofGIV
    {
        copyEntriesGeneralInfoRec(iP)
    }
}

func copyEntriesGeneralInfoRec(iP:NSIndexPath)
{
    switch(iP.row)
    {
    case 0:
        print(iP)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(iP) as! CINametitleTableViewCell
        self.contact.nametitle = Conv().strNothingTostrNull(cell.nametitleTF.text!)
```

the penultimate line occurs the following error:

> ```
> <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} 
> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
> The error happens in the middle code line.
> ```

But the cell should exist, and the right indexPath should be in the iPofGIV Array:

See the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if(indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            let cell = self.editCellsOfGeneralInfo(indexPath)!
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            self.iPofGIV += [indexPath]
            return cell
        }



func editCellsOfGeneralInfo(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?
    {
        switch(indexPath.row)
        {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Nametitle", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! CINametitleTableViewCell
            cell.nametitleTF.text = Conv().strNullToNothing(contact.nametitle)
            return cell
```

What can be the mistake?

Comment: @Tom Pelaia I posted this question again.

Comment: @alex_p I posted this question again.

Comment: Don't get the text from the view (the cell), get it from the model (the data source). Calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is much more expensive than calling the getter of a property. There error occurs because a value is nil when it's not allowed to be nil. Set a breakpoint and check the variables.

Comment: Ok, so I should change the text of the model in the cell class? @vadian

Comment: I mean in `copyEntriesGeneralInfoRec` get the text from the model.

Comment: from which model? Can you help me with a code example, please? @vadian

Comment: The model is the array specified in `tableView:numbersOfRowsInSection:`. The index of the array is in sync with `indexPath.row`. With the given index path retrieve the value from the array. That might not answer your question but the code is much more efficient.

Comment: this is my code: `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch(section)
        {
            case 0: return 7
            case 1: return self.phNumberValues.count
            case 2: return self.emailValues.count
            case 3: return self.extValues.count
            case 4: return 3
            case 5: return 6
            case 6: return 3
            case 7: return 1
            default: return 0
        }
    }`

Comment: I can't follow your idea, please give me a code example ...:-) @vadian

Comment: That's error prone code. In section 0 return also `self......Values.count` for the appropriate array which contains the datasource rather than a constant. And what is `Conv()` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? I suspect that's the reason of the error.

Comment: I have still this mistake... Firstly, you mentioned I shouldn't use `cellForRowAtIndexPath`and I can imagine why I shouldn't use it, but whats a good alternative way to get the content of the cell? I am really glad to get your help! @vadian

Comment: I wrote not to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`in `copyEntriesGeneralInfoRec`. The content of the cell (the view) is a mirror of the datasource array (the model).  To set `self.contact.nametitle` get the data from the data source.  Of course the implicit call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of the table view delegate protocol is necessary.

Comment: Ok, can you give me the line of code of the implicit call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, in my case please? @vadian

Comment: You have it in your code: It's the overridden function `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It gets called by the table view delegate. But you should avoid to call it yourself if possible like in the `copyEntriesGeneralInfoRec`.  Once again: Don't get the data from the cell, get it from the data source array. No offense: Please read the basics about MVC (Model-View-Controller pattern).

Comment: Ok, a really big thanks! @vadian